# FizzBuzz in Rust

Tags: rust, fizzbuzz

I want to make fizzbuzz method return the resolved value and then pass it to println!. Been having quite a problem with &str vs String. Wanted to use &str as return value as it's immutable so I tought it fit nicely though I couldn't get it right.

Here is my String impl:

```
fn main() {
    let ss = "FizzBuzz";
    for i in 1..100 {
        println!("{}", fizzbuzz(i))
    }
}

fn fizzbuzz(value: i32) -> String {
    return match (value % 3, value % 5) {
        (0, 0) => "FizzBuzz".into(),
        (0, _) => "Fizz".into(),
        (_, 0) => "Buzz".into(),
        (_, _) => value.to_string()
    };
}
```

Is there a way to make it simpler without calling straight `println!("Fizzbuzz")` and so on?

Comment: This code is very "simple" to me. Can you define what would make it "simpler" to you?

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079077/proper-way-to-return-a-new-string-in-rust

Comment: I don't like those into() calls - it seems as it's unnecessary but can't find a way to do that properly. Also would prefer to use &str instead of mutable String as I'm not gonna change that return value - just want to print it.

Comment: See also [Simplest way to write FizzBuzz in Rust](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127485/simplest-way-to-write-fizzbuzz-in-rust)

Comment: See also [FizzBuzz in Rust](https://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html)

Comment: And that's not how &str vs String works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Wanted to use &str as return value as it's immutable

That is not possible because the function may produce a new, owned string out of `value`, in this line:

```
    (_, _) => value.to_string()
```

All other match arms could return a `&'static str` since they are string literals, but the output of this one is a `String`. And the fact that you will not mutate the string doesn't change things here, because a new string needs to be constructed anyway.

For cases where a value may either borrow or own the data, you may consider using a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).

```
fn fizzbuzz(value: i32) -> Cow<'static, str> {
    match (value % 3, value % 5) {
        (0, 0) => "FizzBuzz".into(),
        (0, _) => "Fizz".into(),
        (_, 0) => "Buzz".into(),
        (_, _) => value.to_string().into()
    }
}
```

This function will be slightly more efficient memory-wise: the first three guards will return a borrowed static string (`Cow::Borrowed`), whereas the last one will own a string (`Cow::Owned`). The `.into()` calls are necessary for the conversion from the base type (either `&str` or `String`) to a `Cow`.

Other issues:

- `return` statements at the end of a function are redundant. You can just write the expression without a semi-colon at the end.
- you are not using the variable `ss` in `main`.
- although entirely subjective, `u32` may be used instead of `i32` when negative numbers are never considered in your program logic.

> Is there a way to make it simpler without calling straight `println!("Fizzbuzz")` and so on?

Other than the given suggestions, I'm afraid that the given code appears simple and readable enough. That function does not hold a very complex logic.